# Determine the Expected Value of Uniformly random elements of sets

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, random-variables, expected-value

[image]

**Answer is D**

The way I attempted this was that for X = MAX(a,b), the random variable X is equivalent to the max value of a and b. So, from the 2 sets, the probability of getting k from set {1,2...100} is $\frac{k}{100}$ and for the second set we have to select $\frac{k-1}{100}$ so that it is less than the first one.

E(X) would then just be the summation of $x*$$\frac{{k*}{(k-1)}}{100}$, which is option B.

Don't understand how its D? Any explanations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your general logic is fine, although you calculate the probability incorrectly. Note that, if $\max(a,b) = k$, then we have one of three cases:

1. $a = k$ and $b < k$.
2. $a < k$ and $b = k$.
3. $a = b = k$

It should be readily apparent that these cases are disjoint, so to find the probability $P(X = k)$, we can add the probabilities of these cases.

Since $a,b$ are uniform, it's really a matter of counting how many ways this can happen. There's one way for $a = k$ to happen and $k-1$ ways for $b < k$, so multiplying these gives $k-1$ ways; similarly, there's also $k-1$ ways to get $a < k$ and $b = k$. Finally, there's exactly one way to get $a = b = k$. Adding these gives you $1 + 2(k - 1)$; we divide by $100^2$ as the total number of outcomes for $a,b$. This give the probability $P(X = k) = \frac{1 + 2(k-1)}{100^2}$, from which you can derive the expected value in the way you do above.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the disjoint terminology. I'm assuming that means there is nothing in common with those 3 cases? If so, doesn't case 1 and 2 have a=k and b=k common with case 3? Does that make it not disjoint and you can't add probabilities (assuming again you can add probabilities only for disjoint?)

Comment: By disjoint, I mean that the cases have no overlap -- no outcome can be in multiple cases at once. You're right in noting disjointness is required to add probabilities. But it's impossible for case $3$ to overlap with either of the other two, because if $a=k$ and $b=k$, then one of the conditions has to break (because case 1 requires $b < k$ and case 2 requires $a < k$).

Comment: Oh, I understand what you mean now! Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:
$$E(X)=\sum_{k=1}^{100} P(X\ge k)$$
$$P(X\ge k)=1-P(X\le k-1)$$
$$P(X\le k)=P(a\le k\text{ and }b\le k)$$